# Python version is 3.2 at the prompt, 2.6 in scripts

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.6

The default version of python on Snow Leopard is 2.6. I decided to upgrade to 3.2 using an installer from the python website, which installed both 32 and 64 bit versions of python (useful for some libraries.)

The issue is that my python scripts written like 3.2 interpret as 2.6, while my python shell interprets as 3.2
What I wrote may not make sense.

So I have a script which says this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print(sys.version)#note the python 3 syntax
```

When I run it I get this:

```
$ ./test.py 
2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]
```

When I run the same thing at the python prompt I get this:

```
$python
Python 3.2.3 (v3.2.3:3d0686d90f55, Apr 10 2012, 11:25:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.2.3 (v3.2.3:3d0686d90f55, Apr 10 2012, 11:25:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
>>>
```

The question is, how do I fix this? I assume it is an installation issue.
Edited to make the name more useful.

Comment: `python` should run python 2; the python 3 binary should be called `python3`. There is a recent PEP to this effect.

Answer (score 1):

At the command line, type `which python` and report the results.  I bet your path is finding Python 3.3 for some reason and it's not the same one as in `/usr/bin/python`.  If they are different, use `#!/usr/bin/env python` in your script to use your path env variable instead of an absolute path to find python.

Comment: According to your advice: `$ which python
/usr/bin/python
`
No surprises here.

Comment: ... hmm!  That's unexpected!  Have you tried switching the first line of your script to `#!/usr/bin/env python` and seeing if that helps regardless?

Comment: I modified my test script changing the first line to `#!/usr/bin/env python` as you suggested. It did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you wrote in your clarification, at the end of your .bash_profile there is an alias being defined:

```
alias python=python3.2
```

This is the culprit. Consider dropping it and you have a more transparent and intuitive situation.

"which python" (I assume it is /usr/bin/which) didn't solve your perceived mystery because it is not aware of aliases. It only finds a python binary in your path.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand what has precedence in your path (/usr/bin or /usr/local/bin), what does 'which python' reveal in the terminal? You'll want to edit your .bash_profile and add in the path to the new python binary, and change the #!/usr/bin/python in your scripts to point to the new python, something like #!/usr/local/bin/python - wherever the installer put Python 3.x

Comment: Here is what the automatic migration tool added to the end of my .bash_profile
`$ cat ~/.bash_profile | tail
# Setting PATH for Python 3.2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
alias 'python'='python3.2'
`

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why running python in a script gave me the 2.6 python, even though running python at the prompt gave me the 3.2 python. I did fix it.
I found the python3 binary and renamed the problematic python binary in my `/usr/bin`. Then I made a symlink from `/usr/bin/python` to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/python3`

I'm still curious what the original problem was, but it's fixed now.